# Is there any trustable enterprise grade master to master (bi directional) replication option available in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, multi-master-replication

We have two independent databases installed in a local network, we have to synchronize these data bases when one database restart after maintenance,

Is there any trustable enterprise grade master to master (bi directional) replication option available in PostgreSQL for this purpose ?

Comment: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/de/resources/postgres-bdr-2ndquadrant/

Comment: Can we use this solution for windows 10 platform ?